# Not able to understand fork() description

Tags: linux, operating-system, virtual-memory

I was studying about virtual memory management from [galvin](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/0470128720) ,I am unable to understand this statement :

> In addition to separating logical memory from physical memory ,virtual
>   memory allows files and memory to be shared by two or more processes
>   through page sharing .This leads to the following benefits
>
> **Virtual memory can allow pages to be shared during process creation with fork() system call,thus speeding up process creation .**

How can pages be shared with `fork()`? Please clarify.

Answer (score 1):

I believe the text is referring to the copy-on-write optimisation done for fork().

Basically a fork() clones a process, duplicating its entire memory.
This can take a long time, especially for processes which use a lot of money. Moreover, it's very common for a fork() to be immediately followed by an exec(), rendering the previous copy pointless.

Instead of doing all of that work for every fork() modern Unixes create the new process, but don't copy all of the memory. They just point the virtual memory pages for both the original process and the new one to the same physical pages.

This greatly reduces the cost of a fork(), in terms of reduced copies and reduced memory usage.

The downside is that whenever either the fork()ed process or the original process write to a page the write raises an exception (because the physical pages are marked read-only) and the page is copied after all.
Fortunately it turns out this doesn't happen all that often.

Answer (score 0):

pages may be shared by fork if two processes having same or different virtual address page share same physical memory frame. they have same entry of frame number in their page table